# How can I make this for loop faster?

Tags: python, for-loop, load, processing-efficiency, coding-efficiency

```
block = np.ones(len(final_ME))

for k in range(len(final_ME)):
    blockiteration_sum = 0
    for i in range(h):
        blockiteration = math.exp((v1_h[final_ME['year'].iloc[k]][i])+ Sel_PO.dot(Gamma_pow[i][final_ME['year'].iloc[k]].dot(final_ME.iloc[k,6:9].transpose())))
        blockiteration_sum =  blockiteration_sum + blockiteration
   
    block[k] = blockiteration_sum
```

where h=1000
and len(final_ME) = 103000

this code doesn't load, is there any way to make it smoother and load the for loop faster?

Comment: try summing the relevant rows/columns and then using df.pow() to get the exponent?

Comment: What are all the functions that you are using? Is final_ME a dictionary? It all depends on the constant factor, which the answer of these two questions effect.